# Android custom progress view

Tags: android, android-canvas, uiprogressview

I am building a custom like progress view as in Samsung S Health app. Shown below is the screen shot.

[image]

I am able to build a circular view something like this:

[image]

But not sure how to build like the S health one (ellipse shape).
Did any of you tried or have idea how to build this?

Comment: r u showing custom progress-view or using progress-bar?

Comment: @Pratik Its a custom progress-view, using canvas drawing and stuff.

Comment: k got it..i haven't worked it yet.but the purpose is to show progress as it is going on.

Comment: here you can find how to draw the circular progress view.(not the S health one)   https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel/blob/master/src/com/todddavies/components/progressbar/ProgressWheel.java

Comment: use a Path http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html with lineTo and arcTo methods

Comment: probably they use a bunch of different images and do a frame animation just like the facebook sign in progress dialog.

Comment: @AndroSelva please have a look at this library :https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel  I used this to draw custom progress view (2nd one among the screenshots shown in my question). Can i alter this to get something like the S health one.?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Canvas.drawPath() method that allows you to do any type of magic.

Also I'm currently working on a library that will contain progress views with different animations.
You can check it out here, maybe it will help you:
https://github.com/vulko/AnimatedArcProgressView